# Perl - Win32::OLE::const error

Tags: perl, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I’m trying to use WinSCP for SFTP with a Perl script. I’m pretty much using the code off of the [WinSCP site](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_perl) verbatim.  But I’m getting the following error:

> Win32::OLE::CONST->Load: No or invalid type library name at test.pl
>   line 12. Win32::OLE(0.1712): GetOleTypeLibObject() Not a
>   Win32::OLE::TypeLib object at C:/Perl/lib/Win32/OLE/Const.pm line 49.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

My code:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const;
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
 
Win32::OLE->Initialize(Win32::OLE::COINIT_OLEINITIALIZE);
my $session = Win32::OLE->new('WinSCP.Session');
 
my $consts = Win32::OLE::Const->Load($session);
 
my $sessionOptions = Win32::OLE->new('WinSCP.SessionOptions');
```

Comment: Why are you using WinSCP instead of Perl SFTP modules like [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.89/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm)

Comment: I feel like this should be a comment. But short answer is I’m experimenting with multiple technologies including Net::SFTP::Foreign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have [registered WinSCP .NET assembly for COM](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install):

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\RegAsm.exe WinSCPnet.dll /codebase /tlb
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19524610)

Comment: @Shikkediel Even though I somewhat expected to be blamed for posting a link-only question, I honestly believed that the answer stands on its own. All the OP needed to know was that the assembly needs to be registered for COM. How to register an assembly for COM is rather a common knowledge. And even if OP is not familiar with that, it is easy to be googled for. Anyway, I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It easily solved my issue. :)